# Substitution of ACD|BCD like regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

A, B, C and D represent different parts of a regular expression.

The effect I want to achieve:
The input string is ACD or BCD. After substituting C with E, the output should be AED or BED.

The regular expression I used:

```
r=(A)C(D)|(B)C(D)
```

However, the problem arose when I did the substitution.
If I use `r.sub(r'\1s0\2',inputstring)` then there will be an unmatched-group error when the input is BCD. If I use `r.sub(r'\3s0\4',inputstring)` then there will be an unmatched-group error when the input is ACD.

So how can I edit the regular expression to avoid this situation?

Comment: `(A|B)C(D)` replace with `\1E\2`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `(A|B)C(D)` instead of `(A)C(D)|(B)C(D)`:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(A|B)C(D)')
r.sub(r'\1E\2', 'ACD')    # 'AED'
r.sub(r'\1E\2', 'BCD')    # 'BED'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a substitution function instead of string. The return value of the function is used as a replacement string.

```
import re

def repl(m):
    # m: the matched object.
    if m.group(1) is not None:
        prefix, suffix = m.group(1), m.group(2)
    else:
        prefix, suffix = m.group(3), m.group(4)
    return '{}E{}'.format(prefix, suffix)

re.sub('(A)C(D)|(B)C(D)', repl, 'ACD') # AED
re.sub('(A)C(D)|(B)C(D)', repl, 'BCD') # BED
```

Alternatively, if you use [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) instead of Python builtin  `re` module, you can do following:

```
>>> import regex # NOTE: not `re`, but `regex`
>>>
>>> regex.sub('(A)C(D)|(B)C(D)', r'\1\3E\2\4', 'ACD')
'AED'
>>> regex.sub('(A)C(D)|(B)C(D)', r'\1\3E\2\4', 'BCD')
'BED'
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do it by control flow. I'm wondering if I can solve it purely by regular expression.

Comment: @user2923419, If the leading part of the regular expression is fixed length, you can use positive lookaround assertions: `re.sub('(?<=A)C(?=D)|(?<=B)C(?=D)', 'E', 'ACD')`

Comment: @user2923419, I added an alternative solution (using third-party module `regex`). Check it out.